# Response to Sock Puppets

Tags: discussion, user-accounts

There's probably nothing that can officially be done, but we have a new user who seems determined to violate NEC by rewiring their apartment themselves who has created at least 6 sock puppet accounts (that I've noticed, anyway) to ask their various questions, in at least one case [Rewiring and using crown molding](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/257985/18078) having a sock puppet ask the exact same question they asked and apparently deleted with the word "house" substituted for apartment after I commented that they needed a licensed electrician to work on the wiring in a Multiple Dwelling Unit to meet code (they were asking about meeting code, but I have to doubt their sincerity about that at this point.)

Am I mistaken? Is there something that can be done, other than shaking my head at what blatant criminal intent and code violation this represents? Have we got logging of IP addresses to tie the sock puppets together?

Comment: SE doesn't want us getting into the details of the mod tooling, but the challenge is differentiating between one person with multiple accounts, and multiple people from the same location (e.g. co-workers all facing the same problem at the office). I've got this set of accounts on my list to dig into later. Thanks for raising the issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thank you for raising this. The multiple accounts appear to have been created to circumvent moderation controls that limit the number of questions being asked. That is against our policies (described at https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/question-limited) and this issue has been dealt with. If you see further infractions like this, feel free to raise flags or reach out to a moderator.